# i have an issue in making two classes communicatiion the goal is to make one casse accessthe methods and attributes to the other class

Tags: java

i have an issue with somme java code i explain i want to make a relationship between two classes that share somme attributes and commuicate

it is a java game code(simulation)

i will paste a snippet of code

the objectif is to add the properties of an arme(weapon) to the PersoonageArme

that is the objectif

just want to let the two classes communicate

My question is how to get the class PersonnageArme communicate with the class Arme i mean how it can aceess the class Arme methods and attributes ?

PersonnageArme ==> means a person with a weapon

Arme ===========> weapon

BonusAttaque ======> attack bonus

Maxdegats  ================> maximum damage

Lancede  ===================> dice random function(06 faces)

thank you

````
  private static int deNFaces(final int n){
    return (int) (Math.random()*n+1);
    }

  public static int de20(){
    return deNFaces(20);
    }
  public static int de6(){
    return deNFaces(6);
    }
  }


class Personnage  {
/*public static final int MAX_NBPOINTVIE = 12;
public static final int MAX_CLASSARM = 16;*/
public String nom;
public int nbpointsvie;
private int classearmure;

  Personnage p1 = new Personnage("p1");
  Personnage p2 = new Personnage("p2");


  
public Personnage(String otherName, int othernbpointsvie, int autreclassearmure){
  
        nom = otherName;
        nbpointsvie = othernbpointsvie;
        classearmure = autreclassearmure;
    }






public Personnage(String otherName){
        nom = otherName;
        nbpointsvie = LanceDe.de6() + LanceDe.de6();
        classearmure = LanceDe.de20();
    }

    

 
 public String getNom()
 {
 return nom;
 
 }
 
 public int getPointDeVie() 
 {
 return nbpointsvie  ;
 
 }
 
 public int getClasseDArmure()
 
 {
 return classearmure;
 
 }
 

 
  public boolean estVivant(){
  
  
  return nbpointsvie > 0;

    }

  public void recoitDommage(final int dmg){
  
  nbpointsvie = nbpointsvie - dmg;
  
  
    }

  public boolean attaque(final Personnage adversaire){
  
 if (p1.getClasseDArmure() > p2.getClasseDArmure()){
   p1.recoitDommage(1);
   }
 return true;
 

 
  
    }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
   return "Hello";
  
    }
  
}


class Arme   {

/*public static final int BONUS_ATTAQUE = 10;
public static final int MAX_DEGATS= 10;*/
private String nom;   
private String arme;
private int BonusAttaque = 0;
private int MaxDegats = 0;




public Arme(String otherName, String otherarme, int anotherBonusAttaque, int anotherMaxDegats ) {
nom = otherName;
arme = otherarme;

BonusAttaque = anotherBonusAttaque ;

MaxDegats  =  anotherMaxDegats;

 }

 public Arme(String otherName, String otherarme) {
nom = otherName;
arme = otherarme;

BonusAttaque = LanceDe.de6() ;

MaxDegats  =  LanceDe.de6();

 } 
 
public static int getBonusAttaque(final int BonusAttaque ) 
 {
   while ( BonusAttaque > 0){
     
     }

   return  (int) BonusAttaque;
 }
 
  public static int getMaxDegats(final int  MaxDegats  )
 
 {

   while(MaxDegats > 0){

     
   }

 return (int) MaxDegats;
 }
 
public int  infligerDegat(){
int degats =LanceDe.de6(); 
while (degats <  MaxDegats ){
 
 return (int) degats ;

 
   }

  
 
 }
 
 

class PersonnageArme extends Personnage {
private String nom;
private  Arme Arme;


  PersonnageArme testarme1 = new PersonnageArme("Test arme 1", 10, 10);

  PersonnageArme testarme2 = new PersonnageArme("Test arme 2", 10, 10);

 public PersonnageArme(String n, Arme a, int othernbpointsvie, int autreclassearmure) {

  super(n,  Arme a, );

   nom = n;

   Arme = a;
   
  }

  
 public PersonnageArme(String otherName){
 super(otherName );
  
      
 
}
 

public PersonnageArme(String otherName, int othernbpointsvie,  
 int autreclassearmure) {
 super(otherName, othernbpointsvie, autreclassearmure);
  
      
 
}
 
  




 
  public boolean attaque(final PersonnageArme adversaire){
 
 if (testarme.getArme().getBonusAttaque(BonusAttaque)  > Arme.getBonusAttaque(BonusAttaque) || p1.getClasseDArmure() > p2.getClasseDArmure()){
 
 return true;
 
 } 
 

  }```









i would like to get interaction between the two classes Arme  and PersonnageArme


any suggestions would be be very appreciated

thaank you
````

Comment: You did not even post the complete code. We have to guess by reading that snippet. Also the real problem is not clear. Does it not compile? Does it not do what you intend it to?

Comment: the problem is that i want to accesse the methods and attributes of the class Arme from the class PersonnageArme how can i do that please , no it does not compile

Comment: You have a constructor that generates a person with a weapon, and weapons have methods that you can access from an instance of the weapon class. What is preventing you from using that constructor to make a person with a weapon and then use whatever methods you want from the weapon class through the person's weapon?

Comment: if let's say this method in the class PersonnageArme wont work                                            public boolean attaque(final PersonnageArme adversaire){
 
 if (testarme1.getArme().getBonusAttaque(BonusAttaque)  > testarme2.getBonusAttaque(BonusAttaque) || p1.getClasseDArmure() > p2.getClasseDArmure()){
 
 return true;
 
 } 
 

  }

Comment: If the problem is that your code does not compile, post the full code of the class that doesn't compile and the error messages that you see when trying to compile it.

Comment: i wqnted to create a relathionship between the class Arme et PersonnageArme  is there a possible way to do it thank you

Comment: You have already done that, since PersonnageArme already has a field of type Arme

Comment: yes tahk you that is true but i have an error in the constructor

Comment: public PersonnageArme(String n, Arme a, int othernbpointsvie, int autreclassearmure) {

  super(n,  Arme a );  ==========> error

   nom = n;

   Arme = a;
   
  }

Comment: Again, if the problem is that your code does not compile, post the code that does not compile and the error messages

Comment: sorry it was not clear                    super(n,  Arme a ); ==> show error

   nom = n;

   Arme = a;
   
  }

Comment: Again, "show error" means nothing. What error? Please edit your question to include the error messages and a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

You can create communication interface that both Classes implement, that way you can set up communication based on every Claas implementation of the interface methods similiar to listener interface